# Join more than one class including paragraph selector

Tags: css, class, parameters

I want to use this:

```
 .box-03c1 p {line-height: 12.5px;padding: 15px 12px}
 .box-03c2 p {line-height: 12.5px;padding: 15px 12px} 
 .box-03c3 p {line-height: 12.5px;padding: 15px 12px}
 .box-03c4 p {line-height: 12.5px;padding: 15px 12px}
```

But I know there's some way to shorten it...

As you can see the parameters are repetitive.

Any clue?

I will really appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can group all the selectors together like this:

```
.box-03c1 p,
.box-03c2 p,
.box-03c3 p,
.box-03c4 p {
    line-height: 12.5px;padding: 15px 12px
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks a lot! I knew it was a solution like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
[class^="box-"] p{
    line-height: 12.5px;
    padding: 15px 12px;
}
```

This piece of code will apply the attributes to every `p` inside an element with a class that starts with 'box-'. It's a very efficient way to select elements introduced in CSS3

Comment: Depending on use-case, I like this equally well as my proposed solution.

Comment: The methods are identical, so that seems to a logical solution to me

Comment: I like this one, more complex but cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `attribute` type selectors to achieve this:

```
//never used this, but seems to be a great use-case
[class|=box] p {
  line-height: 12.5px;
  padding: 15px 12px;
}
```

**Note** that this will select divs with a class of `box`, as well, and not just `box-*`.

Comment: Interesting, i did not know this one. On the whole though i think I prefer the "starts with" up-caret selector.

Comment: "If the equal sign is preceded by a pipe (|) then the selector will match elements whose attribute values form a hyphenated list of words in which the specified value is present. This operator is primarily intended for the lang attribute." SEE - http://courses.wccnet.edu/~jeggertsen/howtos/css/attribute_selector.html

Comment: Right tool for the job scenario, @Paulie_D, agreed, but if you consider most use cases, this is a good solution more often than I'd've thought. Specifically, it beats having to add/select classes of `box` and `box-asdf`. if classes named carefully/semantically, a box is a box, and this should work fine.